# JS Интерактивная карта

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Подскажите плиз.

Нужно сделать интерактивную карту Украины по областям при этом по каждой области должны выводится какие-то данные из массива(ключ(область)-значение). подскажите плиз по возможной реализации или возможно есть JS библиотека для подобных заданий, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: [Карта Украины SVG](https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=ukraine)  Скачивайте её, а далее делайте по образцу ответа, который приведен в ссылке в  качестве образца дубликата P.S. минус не мой

Answer (score 0):

Какая еще библиотека? Из пушки по воробьям.

Используйте обычный Image map (для удобства задания областей воспользуйтесь онлайн-сервисами, я нагуглил image-map.net). На каждую область уже скриптом навешивайте что угодно (я алерты навесил). На примере - тыкайте в Киевскую и Херсонскую области, все задавать не стал.

```html
<img src="https://annamap.com/ukraine/ukraine-map.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Kiev" title="Kiev" href="kiev" coords="509,130,490,110,445,122,455,203,469,253,452,268,469,323,538,304,556,287,557,258,579,251,597,240,608,212,597,194,588,182,564,194,550,183,538,174,522,160,512,148,510,139" shape="poly" onclick="alert(this.title)">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Kherson" title="Kherson" href="kherson" coords="683,461,677,510,673,530,627,541,596,565,590,582,684,604,716,600,725,580,752,586,780,596,804,598,830,574,811,559,802,549,792,545,781,532,794,517,786,507,768,480,754,481,749,465" shape="poly" onclick="alert(this.title)">
</map>
```